# Create a web page as 2 parts

Tags: asp.net, html

I want to develop a registration form with 2 panels.  One panel is personal information and another is address details.  In these panels the user fills in all details of personal information and after completion of this, the user clicks on `Add Address Details`.  If the user clicks on that, the second panel should be visible without page refresh.  How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

you would use javascript to append the append the second form to to the div of the first form. Or however you have it setup. So in jquery it would look something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#buttonid').click(function() {
    $('#divid').append("<form><input />etc etc etc</form>");
});
</script>
```

Comment: I suggest you read up on jquery api. I cannot spoonfeed you 1. Becauese I do not know how your page is setup and 2. You won't learn anything.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the [ASP.NET Wizard control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163894.aspx). It is the perfect tool for these scenarios. Scott Gu has a post with some links explaining how to use it. I recommend you [look at it.](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/02/21/438732.aspx)There's a video linked that walks you through a full example.

I don't know, but hiding/showing panels based on certain conditions on the same page feels inelegant and hacky to me.

Answer (score 0):

You should look into using an `UpdatePanel`. Within there you could place to `Panels` with different form information. Tie in a few button clicks and hide/show the different panels.

**Edit with a simple example**

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="sm" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
        <asp:UpdatePanel id="upnl" runat="server" ChildrenAsTriggers="true">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:Panel ID="pnl1" runat="server">
                    <!--personal info-->
                    <asp:Button ID="btn1" runat="server" Text="this button could validate personal info, hide pnl1 and show pnl2" />
                </asp:Panel>
                <asp:Panel ID="pn2" runat="server" Visible="false">
                    <!--address info-->
                    <asp:Button id="btn2" runat="server" Text="this button could validate address information and finally submit the form." />
                </asp:Panel>
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: sir am new to asp.net this from for doctor registration for my academic project please can u give details example of the updatepanels\

Comment: @user966602 I've added a simple layout of what you would want to start with, but you'll need to do further research into it. I can't write your code for you.